# How to access a list of Map outside the for loop calling a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Is there a way I can access the `listOfMap` outside the for loop?

```js
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
    getResponseInfo(url,applicationName,list[i]).then(response => {
        var map = convertJsonToMap(response);
        listOfMap.push(map);
    });
}
```

I can see the list of map getting generated inside the loop with each map creation but I want to access the final list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to push all of your promises into a list and then do Promise.all(listOfPromises).then(x => {/*check out the list of map here*/})

Answer (score 1):

You can save all the promises and wait for them to complete.

```
// array to save the promises
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  // getResponseInfo returns a promise
  const promise = getResponseInfo(url, applicationName, list[i]).then(
    (response) => {
      const map = convertJsonToMap(response);
      listOfMap.push(map);
    }
  );
  // save the promise
  promises.push(promise);
}
// wait all promises done
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  // visit the map
});
```